# kummer extension: converse part

Tags: kummer-theory

Let $F$ be a field containing a $n$-th primitive root of unity, now given a finite subgroup $G$ of $F^*/(F^*)^n$, let $K$ be the field containing $F$ and $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^n (F^*)^n\in G$. How to show that kum$(K/F)\cong G$?

Notation: kum$(K/F)=\{ \alpha (F^*)^n: \alpha^n\in F^*\}$

Comment: Unless you have domain your notation (what is kum?) we have to guess. (And my mind-reading machine tells me that you want an equality, not an isomorphism)

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez add the definition of the notation. thanks